# Dijit Checkbox tree event delegation

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.tree

I am trying to implement a dijit checkbox tree similar to http://thejekels.com/dojo/cbtree_AMD.html

And overriding a method like this :

```
      connect.connect( tree, "_onExpandoClick", model, this,function(/*data.item*/ item) {
       console.log("My onExpandoClick");
 });
```

Dijit Tree javascript file already contains the handler method for this event. My problem is that

> I want the above overridden method to be called after tree js method handler
>   have been executed.As per now its always called first.Any idea.(dijit 1.7)

In my setup the below code isn't working :

```
    require(["dijit/TitlePane"]);

    require([
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/aspect",
        "dijit/CheckboxTree", 
        "dojox/data/JsonRestStore",
        "my_ext/CheckboxForestStoreModel", 
        "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(dom, Tree, JsonRestStore, CheckboxForestStoreModel) {
            var treeStore = new JsonRestStore({ target: "ObjectTreeServlet/",labelAttribute:"name",allowNoTrailingSlash:true});
            var treeModel = new CheckboxForestStoreModel({
                    store: treeStore,
                    deferItemLoadingUntilExpand: true,
                    rootId: "ROOT",
                    rootLabel: "NETWORK",
                    childrenAttrs: ["children"],
                    query:"?id=0"         

                });

            var treeStateSession= '<%=session.getAttribute("treeState")%>';
            //alert(treeStateSession);
            var tree = new Tree({
                    id : "tree",
                    model : treeModel,
                    showRoot : false,
                    persist: true,
                    setCheckboxOnClick : false,

                    _sessionVal:treeStateSession
                    },
                'treeDiv');

            function getParameterByName(url,name) {
                var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
                                .exec(url);
                return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }
            dojo.require("dojo.aspect");
            /*
            aspect.after(tree, "_onExpandoClick",  function(item) {
                console.log(tree.getSessionValue());
                document.getElementById("treeState").value=tree.getSessionValue();
                console.log(document.getElementById("treeState").value.length);

            }); */
aspect.after(tree, "_onExpandoClick", function() {
console.log("My onExpandoClick");
```

});

*Code Inside CheckBoxTree.js :*

```
_state: function(node, expanded){
        // summary:
        //      Query or set expanded state for an node
        if(!this.persist){
            return false;
        }
        var path = array.map(node.getTreePath(), function(item){
                return this.model.getIdentity(item);
            }, this).join("/");
        if(arguments.length === 1){
            return this._openedNodes[path];
        }else{
            if(expanded){
                this._openedNodes[path] = true;
            }else{
                delete this._openedNodes[path];
            }
            var ary = [];
            for(var id in this._openedNodes){
                ary.push(id);
            }
            //console.log(ary.length);
            //cookie(this.cookieName, ary.join(","), {expires:365});
            var sessionVal=ary.join(",");
            console.log("TreeSTATE CheckBOX");

     **//FROM HERE SEND sessionVal TO MAIN HTML PAGE WHERE TREE IS CREATED?**

            //this.getSessionValue(ary.join(","));
        }
    },
```

*What I tried ,which is not giving desired results.:*

```
aspect.after(tree, "_state", function() {
                    console.log("TreeSTATE  "  + tree.getSessionValue());
                    document.getElementById("treeState").value=tree.getSessionValue();

                    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`dojo/aspect`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect) instead:

```
// var aspect = require("dojo/aspect");
// var lang   = require("dojo/_base/lang");

aspect.after(tree, "_onExpandoClick", lang.hitch(this, function(item) {
    console.log("My onExpandoClick");
}))
```

**Edit:** Also please note, `dijit/Tree` as well as `cbtree/Tree` emit `onOpen` and `onClose` events, so you can register event listeners for expanding and collapsing node actions:

```
tree.on("open", function(item, node) {
    console.log("onOpen:", item, node);        
});

tree.on("close", function(item, node) {
    console.log("onClose:", item, node);        
});
```

**Edit #2**: According to the discussion below I changed my approach from using `dojo/aspect` to subclassing `Tree` (because of some quirky async funky there). So first subclass `Tree`:

```
// var declare  = require("dojo/_base/declare"); 
// var lang     = require("dojo/_base/lang");
// var Deferred = require("dojo/_base/Deferred");

var MyTree = declare([Tree], {

    persist: true,

    _expandNode: function(node, recursive) {
        var dfd = this.inherited(arguments);
        Deferred.when(dfd, lang.hitch(this, function() {
            if (recursive === undefined) {
                this.set("state", this._objectToArray(this._openedNodes));
            }
        }));
        return dfd;
    },

    _collapseNode: function(node) {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.set("state", this._objectToArray(this._openedNodes));
    },

    _objectToArray: function(object) {
        var arr = [];
        for (var each in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(each)) {    
                arr.push(each);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
});
```

Then you can you can observe expand/collapse state change on `MyTree` instance:

```
tree.watch("state", function(/*String*/key, /*Array*/oldValue, /*Array*/newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);        
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/LcPzv/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, so I put together an example, please look at it and let me know what you do not like there: [http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/LcPzv/](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/LcPzv/). Also note, `Tree` emits `open` event, so you may add listener to it instead: `tree.on("open", function(item, node){})`.

Comment: Hi , have pasted the code . It says JsonTreeStore is not a constructor . If we remove the two require you suggested , tree comes. Any help ?

Comment: `JsonRestStore` is not a constructor, because in `JsonRestStore` variable is `dojo/aspect` module. `require([/*Array*/], function() {/*Factory*/})` - items in require _array_ must match parameters in _factory_ function. Also [AMD loader](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd) is asynchronous, therefore `require(["dijit/TitlePane"])` is not available inside your factory function. Do not mix legacy `dojo.require()` and AMD `require()/define()`. Choose one and stick to it.

Comment: Thanks to your last code addition I finally fully understand what you are about to achieve. I edited the code to meet your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/LcPzv/. I had to subclass `Tree` class, because of some quirky async funky, but now all you need to observe expand/collapse status change is `tree.watch("state", function(key, oldValue, newValue) { /* your handler here */ });`. Hope, this helps.

Comment: But it does in the jsFiddle, or not? I tested it in Chrome, Firefox and IE9. Might be due to version of Dojo? Required `dojo/Stateful` was introduced in Dojo 1.5, but maybe it does not process array changes properly in other than jsFiddle's 1.7. Anyway, you can call whatever you want instead of `this,set("state", ...)`. This `dojo/Stateful` is just nice and readable pattern...

Comment: I am using Dojo 1.7 only . Tree is loading correctly and other event are working fine except the watch event

Comment: What I want to achieve is simple . There is _onExpandoClick Event hander inside tree.js and _state method. _state method saves my session variable which is consumed by -OnExpandoClick overrtidden method in my html . But my -OnExpandoClick gets called before _state method so the very last path is not getting updated to my html.

Comment: I tried to assign the `this._openedNodes` object into `state` property and it did not work, so maybe it is the same with array (which works fine with Dojo 1.7.4), so try to make it a string. Do you instantiate `MyTree` and not `Tree`? The main point here is that `_expendNode` calls `this.set("state", ...)` only after the `this._openedNodes` object reflect the state of tree, because opening a node is asynchronous and recursive action.

Comment: Hi Phusick , thank your very much for your continues support. It is finally working for me . I am accepting the answer . Hope to see in other dojo thread. Thanks again.

Comment: You too have a beautiful day :)